# opencv color detection for particular region

Tags: python, opencv, colors, image-recognition

I want to have a **color detection** for a **particular region** in a video.
For example, my program will detect people and bound him with **a rectangular box.**

```
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
(rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(image, winStride=(4, 4),
    padding=(8, 8), scale=1.05)

# draw the original bounding boxes
for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
    cv2.rectangle(orig, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Afterwards, I want to **check whether the brown color** within the box is greater than threshold. If yes, the program print "detected".

How can I only detect the color within a specified region?

Comment: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/

Comment: It is similar to want I want, but I only want to have a Boolean value (brown color intensity is greater than threshold or not). I do want to convert the color of the image.

Comment: detect people, compare the brown color with a threshold... Hmmm, looks like Donald Trump software...

Comment: I am not from US. I am not doing sth. like Donald Trump lol. I just want to detect who is wearing brown pants.

Answer (score 0):

Use Rect object. I'm not coding OpenCV in Python but I think it'll be look like this:

```
rect = cv2.Rect(x, y, width, height)
region = image(rect)
```

Now instead of image pass region into your algorithms.